# Wicket encoding issue on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, character-encoding, wicket

I am a google app engine newbie.
I have an encoding issue with a wicket application in GAE.
(see http://ristorante-lastoria.appspot.com/wicket/home )

My IDE is configured to save the HTML template files in UTF-8.

I ve printed out the default file.encoding used by GAE JVM and it's ASCII.
I 've tried to set the following parameters in the appengine-web.xml.

```
<system-properties>
<property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
</system-properties>
<env-variables>
<env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
<env-var name="APP_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</env-variables>
```

I ve tried to set the flag --compile-encoding=UTF-8 when uploading the war content to the server.

At the build level(using maven), I tried to escape the unicode characters in the build using the native2ascii tool.
No luck so far :-(

Wicket version: 1.4.17

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a xml declaration wirh encoding to all your templates:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Comment: Thx a lot, Sven, that fixed the issue. I've also configured my Application subclass to strip the xml declaration. `code` getMarkupSettings().setStripXmlDeclarationFromOutput(true);